# Angular 2 determine if Event is handled

Tags: angular

**Updated to better illustrate what I am trying to do:**

I would like to use a reflection type method to basically disable certain functionality and update the presentation if the event is or isn't handled by the parent component.

Example:

Imagine a component tree of GroceryCart with contains a list of GroceryItem.  The GroceryItem has output events of onDelete and onQuantityEdit.  Those events are emitted by the GroceryItem to the parent GroceryCart component to handle those particular events.

Now the user is checking out and you are showing a ConfirmCheckOut component which contains a list of GroceryItem.  In the ConfirmCheckOut component, a user does not delete items or update quantities anymore, so the ConfirmCheckOut component does not handle the OnDelete or OnQuantityEdit events emitted by the GroceryItem.

If the GroceryItem knew that it's parent component did not handle those events, then it could update it's own UI so that functionality was hidden.  So, if the parent was ConfirmCheckOut, then GroceryItem component could hide it's delete and update quantities button.  If the parent is GroceryCart, then delete and update quantities buttons would be there and available to the user.

Is there a way to do this in Angular 2?

Comment: Quite abstract. What about more concrete information like a concrete example with some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could *attempt* (I do not recommend) injecting the parent into your child component and checking it's prototype for your needed functions.

```
export class ChildComponent {
    private hasAddItem = false;

    constructor(@Host() parentComponent: ParentComponent){
        this.hasAddItem = !!parentComponent.protoType.addItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this but thought it broke the component tree architecture so I didn't want to do it.  I was hoping there was some sort of hook in the child component to know what events are handled.  The way I am leaning to handling this is defining a functionality object for the component and have that as an input parameter.  But that seems a pain to maintain over time.  Was just hoping there was a more succinct way of doing this.

Comment: I think this problem domain will inherently create scaling and maintainability issues.  The real answer is that the child shouldn't care about who is handling that event.

Comment: This is a solution to my originally stated question.  I don't think it's the right thing to do because it violates separation of concerns so I guess the answer to my question is: "can do this technically but shouldnt do this".

Answer (score 0):

The below code is present in your App component's HTML

```
<grocery-cart [cartItems]="selectedItems"> </grocery-cart>
<grocery-products (selectedItem)="handleSelecteditem($event)"> </grocery-products>
```

AppComponent should handle the event add add it the selectedItems variable as below

```
handleSelecteditem(item:Product){
    this.selectedItems.push(item);
}
```

grocery-cart should contain code as below

```
template:`
    <div *ngFor="let product in products">
        <image >
        <description>
    </div>
    <button (click)="checkout()"> Checkout </button>
`
@Input() cartItems :Array<Product>
```

grocery-products Component code must look like

```
template:`
    <div *ngFor="let product in products">
        <image >
        <description>
        <button (click)="addToCart(product)"> Add to Cart </button>
    </div>
`
```

Variables :

```
@Output() selectedItem:EventEmitter<Product>=new EventEmitter<Product>();
products:Array<Product>;
```

Methods :

```
addToCart(item : Product){
        this.selectedItem.emit(item);
    }
```

I have created an abstract as above, but this changes based on how complex your application is going to be and the architecture